# Can Android save state on powerloss?

Tags: restore

Does Android support hibernation?

I'm interested specifically in two scenarios:

- Resuming after a "nice" powerdown - ie, the phone runs out of power during normal use (say, in the middle of writing or reading email)
- Resuming after a "catastrophic" powerdown - ie, say the battery accidentally is removed in the middle of some sort of activity.

Comment: I would think that would more be a function of the individual applications, not the phone/os. A program can do running backups to restore state, for example. I don't know about your first scenario for restarting apps. But I'm pretty sure nothing can help with #2

Comment: Without using flash storage (or something else that preserves state without power) as RAM you can't have #2, and that's slow and expensive (you'd burn out and need to replace it quickly).  Listing phones would count as a shopping rec, I think, so I'm going to tweak this if that's OK.

Comment: If the battery is removed then it can't "resume" because it has nothing to resume from. Hibernation still uses some energy.

Comment: @Demizide no it doesn't. Hibernation is when you save your ram to permanent memory and then restore it on bootup. 'Sleep' means shutting down everything except ram. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hibernation_(computing)#Comparison_to_sleep_mode

Comment: Yeah, I was really tired when I wrote that

Comment: I've heard newer HTC phones support this feature, then again it's something they've added on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Android system does not natively support any kind of resume after a full shutdown. Individual apps can save their state at any time and restore that state when the app is loaded, but the Android system cannot store its state or the state of all of the apps for a shutdown. Theoretically speaking, the kernel could probably be modified to support some form of hibernation but the stock Android system does not.